# Not registering on Asterisk over VPN

Tags: linux, networking, openvpn, sip, asterisk

[image]

I want to work in local area from home, I configured OpenVPN on my Asterisk server (it is only one Linux server in LAN), it works fine.

I enabled forwarding on Asterisk server, and client now can see LAN (net 192.168.1.0/24). But if I try to register on Asterisk, it fails. In Asterisk tun0 dump I see "Server error 500" in SIP packet.

What prevents me from registering? SIP/RTP ports range?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have ensure you start asterisk server AFTER tunnel connected. Otherwise it will not see new address

Second you have check your client NOT use NAT and not put client's external ip in packet(usually mean you have disable STUN)

Also you can check from BOTH side where packets go using mtr utility or get trace by using tcpdump.

You can see more info on asterisk using sip debug

```
asterisk -r
sip set debug on
```